# NUnit running the wrong test assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit

I'm running NUnit from VS2k8 by setting it as the start action for the test project.  That worked fine when I only had a single solution with a single test project.  I'm trying to run tests in a second solution now, but when NUnit launches it's loading Solution1Name.Test instead of Solution2Name.test

Comment: Adding Solution2Name.test.dll to the passed command line arguments is working.  I'm not happy about having to put more configuration data that should be teamwide in nature in what's intended as a user specific file (Solution2Name.test.csproj.user) though.

Answer (score 2):

NUnit reloads the last configuration that it used before it closes. Its a feature of the application to help you test faster. if you need to move to another projects just use the Open function and find the assembly you wish to test with.